# Trying to run `pass` password manager through cron job

Tags: terminal, password, homebrew

I'm using `pass` password manager through Homebrew. I am trying to setup a cron job to run the following script (I named it `pass_sync.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/pass git push
```

**Crontab line:**

`*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /Users/myuser/.scripts/pass_sync.sh`

(I've set it to one minute for debugging purposes, it will be done every 30 mins)

The notification I get from `cron` on my email inbox is:

```
Error: could not create filesystem on ramdisk.
/usr/local/Cellar/pass/1.7.4/lib/password-store/platform.sh: line 22: umount: command not found
/usr/local/Cellar/pass/1.7.4/lib/password-store/platform.sh: line 23: diskutil: command not found
```

**/usr/local/Cellar/pass/1.7.4/lib/password-store/platform.sh:**

```
1 # Copyright (C) 2012 - 2014 Jason A. Donenfeld <Jason@zx2c4.com>. All Rights Reserved.
  2 # This file is licensed under the GPLv2+. Please see COPYING for more information.
  3 
  4 clip() {
  5         local sleep_argv0="password store sleep for user $(id -u)"
  6         pkill -f "^$sleep_argv0" 2>/dev/null && sleep 0.5
  7         local before="$(pbpaste | $BASE64)"
  8         echo -n "$1" | pbcopy
  9         (
 10                 ( exec -a "$sleep_argv0" sleep "$CLIP_TIME" )
 11                 local now="$(pbpaste | $BASE64)"
 12                 [[ $now != $(echo -n "$1" | $BASE64) ]] && before="$now"
 13                 echo "$before" | $BASE64 -d | pbcopy
 14         ) >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
 15         echo "Copied $2 to clipboard. Will clear in $CLIP_TIME seconds."
 16 }
 17 
 18 tmpdir() {
 19         [[ -n $SECURE_TMPDIR ]] && return
 20         unmount_tmpdir() {
 21                 [[ -n $SECURE_TMPDIR && -d $SECURE_TMPDIR && -n $DARWIN_RAMDISK_DEV ]] || return
 22                 umount "$SECURE_TMPDIR"
 23                 diskutil quiet eject "$DARWIN_RAMDISK_DEV"
 24                 rm -rf "$SECURE_TMPDIR"
 25         }
 26         trap unmount_tmpdir INT TERM EXIT
 27         SECURE_TMPDIR="$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$PROGRAM.XXXXXXXXXXXXX")"
28         DARWIN_RAMDISK_DEV="$(hdid -drivekey system-image=yes -nomount 'ram://32768' | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" # 32768 sec    tors = 16 mb
 29         [[ -z $DARWIN_RAMDISK_DEV ]] && die "Error: could not create ramdisk."
 30         newfs_hfs -M 700 "$DARWIN_RAMDISK_DEV" &>/dev/null || die "Error: could not create filesystem on ramdisk."
 31         mount -t hfs -o noatime -o nobrowse "$DARWIN_RAMDISK_DEV" "$SECURE_TMPDIR" || die "Error: could not mount fi    lesystem on ramdisk."
 32 }
 33 
 34 qrcode() {
 35         if type imgcat >/dev/null 2>&1; then
 36                 echo -n "$1" | qrencode --size 10 -o - | imgcat
 37         else
 38                 echo -n "$1" | qrencode -t utf8
 39         fi
 40 }
 41 
 42 GETOPT="$({ test -x /usr/local/opt/gnu-getopt/bin/getopt && echo /usr/local/opt/gnu-getopt; } || brew --prefix gnu-g    etopt 2>/dev/null || { which port &>/dev/null && echo /opt/local; } || echo /usr/local)/bin/getopt"
 43 SHRED="srm -f -z"
 44 BASE64="openssl base64"
```

#### When I specify the full path on the script that `cron` runs, this is the error I get:

```
Error: could not create filesystem on ramdisk.
umount: /tmp/pass.rSiPwPfw10cHa: not currently mounted
```

Comment: Does the script work from the terminal? How does the documentation for pass say the ramdisk is created?

Comment: @mmmmmm hello! The script works perfectly from the terminal. The only thing I could find about `pass`and this error, is a long lost thread by someone here: https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/password-store/2015-August/001706.html

But that's all there is (or that I could find).  Up to this point, I'm either guess I won't be pushing my passwords to git vía `cron` or simply trying with a launchd daemon? What would be your recommendation? Thanks again!

Comment: Reading the error messages about unfound commands. This looks like the usual issue the environment e.g. PATH differs between interactive use and cron/launchd. Many answers here will tell you use full paths for executables in scripts or set the path in the scriot

Comment: @mmmmmm yes I know! And it's what I did.  The unfound command errors are gone and now I'm only getting the "Could not create fs on Ramdisk".

Comment: SO what is the line that creates the ramdisk?

Comment: Sorry @mmmmmm! I've edited the question so you can see the part of the code in question.

Comment: @mmmmmm mmmm... actually I see the command mount there, maybe I should also use the full path on that one? Let's see.

Comment: what is the value of DARWIN_RAMDISK_DEV? Add an echo to the script right before newfs_hfs.

Comment: Hi again @nohillside! It's not set. However, I noticed that using the full paths on the script (`platform.sh`) did break the `pass git push`command. I returned `platform.sh`to its original backup and now it works ok.

So we're basically at the error on line 22 and 23: `umount and diskutil` commands not found.

Comment: Please update the question to show the exact errors you get and the current version of the script

Comment: Also, if DARWIN_RAMDISK_DEV is not set, you should get "Error: could not create ramdisk", and not the error you show in the question.

Comment: Hello @nohillside! I've edited the question to show the current state of affairs.

Comment: `umount` and `diskutil` are in /sbin and /usr/sbin, respectively, but the default `PATH` for cron jobs doesn't include those directories (just /bin and /usr/bin). Either set `PATH` to somethine more complete in the script, or specify the full paths for those commands (or both).

Comment: Hello @GordonDavisson! Thanks for your input, can you teach me how to set PATH on the script? Do I simply export it or?
I have tried specifying the full paths on the commands, it did not work. I will add the output when I specify it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I have added the error I get when specifying the full paths on the script that `cron ` runs, it's at the end of the question.

Comment: You could set a more reasonable `PATH` by adding `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` near the beginning of the script. As for the other errors, the script tends to discard command output and error messages with `>/dev/null 2>&1` or `&>/dev/null`; it's likely the suppressed error messages would have useful information about what's really going wrong. I'd remove those redirects (at least until you get the problem figured out) and see what the full errors show.

Comment: Well, setting the PATH variables and removing the error messages got me this error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured`

I am starting to think that the idea of pushing passwords through a cron job is a little bit futile hehe.